# Trying to make a certificate for my Spanish teacher

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, gramática

I am making an end-of-year certificate for my Spanish teacher, and just need a quick confirmation that this is right.

> Una profesora increíble con mucho entusiasmo y tiene mucho amor por
>   sus alumnos.

Gracias!

Comment: Sounds good! I would say `..., que tiene mucho amor`, instead of `y tiene`.

Comment: I agree with @fedorqui but I would change the second _mucho_ to avoid being repetitive. I would go with: `Una profesora increíble con mucho entusiasmo y un gran amor por sus alumnos`.

Comment: It would be helpful to show us more of the letter so we can improve it overall. If you want of course.

Comment: You could also say una profesora increíble que tiene mucho entusiasmo y amor por sus alumnos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have said...

> Una profesora increíble con mucho entusiasmo, tiene mucho amor por sus alumnos.

Or....

> Una profesora increíble con mucho entusiasmo y amor por sus alumnos.

¡Saludos! :D

Answer (score 0):

> Una profesora increíble, con mucho entusiasmo y amor por sus alumnos.

In English you need to use a "," before the "and". However, in Spanish is not necessary.